# How can I get a new instance of a class to happen automatically at a certain time using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, so if someone can point me to another post please do.

I'd like to have a 'round' class that starts at a certain time each day or after a certain countdown? Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but I feel you want a background job, which runs after every few hours to do some task for you. You can create cron job for that https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: If you're talking about triggering a job on the background at specific times, you should take a look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), if you want to trigger something when countdown ends, then you should take a look at [timers](https://github.com/socketry/timers). What you could then is, you could use them together, and trigger background job when the timer ends or at a specified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For certain time each day, you can check [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

For starting after a certain countdown, you can read about [Active Job](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Just starting points for you to figure out what you need.